# Hartl's Rails Tutorial seeding db too much data to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I am having an issue in chapter 13 when seeding Microposts to users.  On my local AWS Cloud 9 environment it seeds 50 microposts per user just fine but when resetting and reseeding on Heroku it seeds almost 5k posts per user.  After going back through the chapter I can't see anything about changing anything for Heroku.  Any tips?  Here is my seed code

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(word_count: 5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```

Comment: Where/how does this code get called?

Comment: I believe it's his `db/seed.rb` file